# Seeking alternative to ArcPy to translate feature class

Tags: qgis, arcpy, software-recommendations, move, translate

I'm using `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` to move shape based in X and Y translation.

```
with arcgis.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, ["SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + 100000,row[0][1] + 8200000]])
```

But ArcPy needs licence and only can be used into ArcGIS environment. How can I do similar with alternative libraries, maybe in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [.translate](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.translate) method of QgsGeometry:

```py
#Create layer. You can also use the layer added to the map (vl = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("buffered")[0])
fc = r'/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/movethem.gpkg|layername=buffered'
vl = QgsVectorLayer(fc)

#Distance to move the geometry in x and y directions. In the units of the layer crs
deltax = -7000
deltay = -5000

with edit(vl): #Start an edit session
    for feat in vl.getFeatures(): #For each feature
        geom = feat.geometry() #Extract its geometry
        _ = geom.translate(deltax, deltay) #Move it
        feat.setGeometry(geom) #Set the features geometry to the modified geometry
        vl.updateFeature(feat) #Update
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may find more success using **Geopandas**. QGIS' library is effective, but in terms of translating files from open-source GIS platforms to the ESRI Suite might bring problems.

```
import geopandas as gpd

#Load SHP
gdf = gpd.read_file("Path_To_Your_Shapefile.shp")

#Classify X/Y Translation Numbers
XT= 100000
YT= 8200000

gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.translate(XT, YT)

#Save to a SHP.
gdf.to_file("Path_To_Your_New_Shapefile.shp")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option... If you like SQL, you can use Geopackage files and do something like this:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import box

gdal.UseExceptions()

# Input
path = "tmp/tmp.gpkg"
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[box(0, 0, 10, 10)], crs=31370)
print(f"before {gdf.total_bounds.tolist()=}")
gdf.to_file(path)

# Translate
ds = gdal.OpenEx(path, nOpenFlags=gdal.OF_UPDATE)
result = ds.ExecuteSQL("UPDATE tmp SET geom = ST_Translate(geom, 10, 10, 0)")
ds.ReleaseResultSet(result)
ds = None

# Result
gdf = gpd.read_file(path)
print(f"after {gdf.total_bounds.tolist()=}")
```